# Where can i get android-common library to add it in gradle build?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am converting android system application "Contacts"  based on Android.mk buid to gradle build ,from Android Studio.

Getting error

> CompositeCursorAdapter symbol is not resolved

.
Which is part of package

```
 import com.android.common.widget.CompositeCursorAdapter;
```

When i checked Android.mk ,Having dependency with android-common ,coudnt find part of android sdk ,

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    com.android.vcard \
    android-common \
```

is this android-common available in maven repo or google repo or part of android sdk ?

Only way i'm finding is ,build full android code & get the library ? .Any other alternative

Comment: what's your target sdk ?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 27

Comment: It should be resolved automatically cause common classes are part of Android sdk. what error you get ?

Comment: error: package com.android.common.widget does not exist

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: clean build & Invalidate Cache is tried ,Same issue
andrid-27 ,android.jar not having package from com.android.common

Comment: maybe just add the class to your source, it seems that CompositeCursorAdapter only uses sdk classes/methods https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/common/java/com/android/common/widget/CompositeCursorAdapter.java